# Undecorated JFrame having problems with resizing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a desktop app (a Markdown editor) in Java, and I'm having problems on frame resizing. The frame I'm working on is **undecorated**. On the left side of the frame is a title bar. The content pane uses a `FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0)` as the
default layout. My problem is when I use the following code to achive resizing function, I can only resize my frame on X and Y axis but not both sides at the same time (when you put your cursor on a vertex of the frame), and the layout isn't working. My goal is to complete a full-functioned resizing system which you can drag and drop the edges of the frame to adjust the size of it.

My Code:

```java
package xmark.ui;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private final TitleBar titleBar = new TitleBar();  // public class TitleBar extends JPanel

    /**
     * The original content pane on the frame. Is a holder of the title bar.
     */
    public JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) getContentPane();


    /**
     * The default constructor. No needs to manually pass in any arguments
     * because it automatically decorates the frame and sets up the title
     * bar. There are two private methods used in the constructor: {@code setUI()}
     * and {@code titleBar()}.
     */
    public MyFrame() {
        setUI();
        titleBar();
    }

    private void setUI() {

        // Basic method settings
        setSize(new Dimension(1200, 750));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(120, 75));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane.setBackground(UIUtilities.BASE_COLOR); // UIUtilities is a ui utility class for this app
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));

        // Sizing function
        contentPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            boolean top = false;
            boolean down = false;
            boolean left = false;
            boolean right = false;
            Point draggingAnchor = null;

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

                double mouseY = e.getPoint().getY();
                double mouseX = e.getPoint().getX();

                if (mouseY > 1 && mouseY < 6) {
                    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR));
                    top = true;

                } else if (Math.abs(mouseY - getSize().getHeight()) <= 5) {
                    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR));
                    down = true;

                } else if (mouseX > 1 && mouseX < 6) {
                    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR));
                    left = true;

                } else if (Math.abs(mouseX - getSize().getWidth()) <= 5) {
                    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR));
                    right = true;

                } else {
                    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                    draggingAnchor = new Point(e.getX() + contentPane.getX(), e.getY() + contentPane.getY());
                    top = false;
                    down = false;
                    left = false;
                    right = false;
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                Dimension dimension = getSize();

                if (top) {
                    dimension.setSize(dimension.getWidth(), dimension.getHeight() - e.getY());
                    setSize(dimension);
                    setLocation(getLocationOnScreen().x, getLocationOnScreen().y + e.getY());

                } else if (down) {
                    dimension.setSize(dimension.getWidth(), e.getY());
                    setSize(dimension);

                } else if (left) {
                    dimension.setSize(dimension.getWidth() - e.getX(), dimension.getHeight());
                    setSize(dimension);
                    setLocation(getLocationOnScreen().x + e.getX(), getLocationOnScreen().y);

                } else if (right) {
                    dimension.setSize(e.getX(), dimension.getHeight());
                    setSize(dimension);

                } else {
                    setLocation(e.getLocationOnScreen().x - draggingAnchor.x, e.getLocationOnScreen().y - draggingAnchor.y);
                }
            }
        });

    }


    private void titleBar() {

        contentPane.add(titleBar);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can check out [Resizing Components](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) for one solution. Just register the frame and you will be able to resize the frame in any direction.